# Concatenation in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I've got a long string I'm trying to concatenate in a `process.start` call, and I'm messing something up with the syntax. Here is what I have so far:

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VS110COMNTOOLS") & .. \Ide\MSTEST.EXE", "/Testsettings:" & rwSettings & " /Testcontainer:" & rwContainer & " /Resultsfile:" & utilnamespace.rwResults)`

So as you can see, I'm trying to start the process `MSTEST.EXE` with a bunch of arguments. My question is mainly around the first bit. I need it to grab the install directory of VS2012 so it knows where to find `MSTEST.EXE` so I'm trying to be clever and use the environment variable, but that returns the tools directory... so I need it to back up a step and get to the IDE directory.

I'm hoping to do this without having to define my own function to find the install directory from the registry entry. Any idea how I can get it to do the equivalent of `..`?

Comment: Just put the .. in the path. `"..\ide\mstest.exe"`

Comment: I thought that would just get parsed as a string and fail, but I'll give that a shot.

Comment: And just for the record: `String.Concat("str1", "str2", "str3")`

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I'd go for String.Format over that actually. `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String.Format("{0}..\Ide\MSTEST.EXE /Testsettings:{1} /Testcontainer:{2} /Resultsfile:{3}",Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VS110COMNTOOLS"),rwContainer,utilnamespace.rwResults));`

Answer (score 4):

The safest way to perform directory concatenation is to use [IO.Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim msTestPath As String
msTestPath = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VS110COMNTOOLS"), "..\Ide\MSTEST.EXE")
```

This will automatically ensure that the directories are properly terminated. If you just do straight string concatenation and someone or something has removed the trailing \ from the environment variable, then straight string concat will yield incorrect results (i.e. \tools..ide\ instead of \tools..ide).